# How to convert a Ruby bitstring into a Float?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Suppose we have a 64-character string representing the bits of a Ruby `Float`. The bits are in big-endian order. For instance, this string is for 12.125:

```
"0100000000101000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

I'd like to `#unpack` this back into the corresponding `Float` (that is, the answer should be `[12.125]`). What's the neatest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up interpreting the string as a long unsigned integer, packing the bytes of that integer, and then unpacking the corresponding float:

```
s = "0100000000101000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[s].pack("B*").unpack("G") #=> [12.125]
```

[Edit: amended to include Alex's suggestion.]

Answer (score 2):

Your provided answer works great, but if you want to skip the conversion to int you can also do

```
s = "0100000000101000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[s].pack("B*").unpack("G") #=> [12.125]
```

Comment: Nice, I'd forgotten about `B*`! Thanks.